# How can we enable drop down on title bar (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS), like the one we have for bookmark drop down arrows in browsers?

Tags: titlebar

The following is the bar I am referring to:

[image]

And this is what appears to be missing / or can be added but I do not know how:

[image]

This arrow appears in bookmark in browser. But is there any way we can bring this to the title bar in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS so in case of extension overflow, we can select easily which extension to show and which not to show from time to time?

Thank you very much!

Comment: From the Extensions tool or Gnome Tweaks, you can easily turn extensions on or off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the extension "[Extension list](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3088/extension-list/)" to create a button on your top panel that allows you to enable/disable extensions. You can also configure extensions from that drop down menu.

Alternatively, you can turn on/off extensions using Gnome Tweaks or using the Extensions tool (Ubuntu 20.04 and upwards). Both are not installed by default in Ubuntu, but are available in the software center.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Though right now I have removed some extensions so my list is not long but this is a very useful extension to have. This will solve my problem if I will have more extensions. Thanks @vanadium :)

Comment: You are welcome :)